Using Power Automate to move SharePoint folders with # character in their names
I've created a flow to move folders from a folder (originating) to another folder (destination) using a schedule trigger, but when a folder has the # character in its name, all the files are moved and the folder structure is copied, but the folder is not deleted from the originating folder.
I've tried all the options I could: sending http request, using PA actions, copying the folder and then trying to delete it from the originating folder, but nothing worked.
Has anyone encountered this problem?

You can use encodeURIComponent() to specify the encoded values for those special characters in rest api like following
encodeURIComponent("A#B")

